# fluent-nhibernate: not getting the records

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have an entity like

```
public class SKU
{
    //public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FactoruCode { get; set; }
    public string Ptoduct { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping defined as

```
 public class SKUMap : ClassMap<SKU>
    {
        public SKUMap()
        {            
            Table("MST_PRODUCT");
            Not.LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Ptoduct).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
            Map(x => x.Ptoduct, "PRODUCT_NAME");
            Map(x => x.FactoruCode, "FACTORY_CODE");
        }
    }
```

and retrieving the records like

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var skus = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SKU)).List<SKU>();
                foreach (var sku in skus)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sku.Ptoduct);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        var cfg = OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10
            .ConnectionString(c =>
                              c.Is(
                                  @"DATA SOURCE=SERVER_NAME;PERSIST SECURITYINFO=True;USER ID=USER_ID;Password=PWD"));
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(cfg).Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema).BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    private static void BuildSchema(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config)
    {
        new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
    }

}
```

but the table has more columns than specified for entity. This code executes well, but I'm not able to get the list of SKUs (table has more than 8000 rows).

Please help me to understand the problem.

Comment: You say that the code executes well and ask for help understanding an error? Are you getting an exception? If so, what is the exception?

Comment: Hi Jai, i m sure that code is compiling well. this is a console application .

Answer (score 2):

Your SKU map is wrong. Why have you defined `PRODUCT_NAME` as an Id column? You need to fix it by setting the Id to an Id column (which you have commented out):

```
Id(x => x.Id, "NAME_OF_YOUR_ID_COLUMN_HERE").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
Map(x => x.Ptoduct, "PRODUCT_NAME");
```

If `PRODUCT_NAME` is indeed the Id, you need to set it like this:

```
Id(x => x.Ptoduct, "PRODUCT_NAME").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

and remove the other line:

```
Map(x => x.Ptoduct, "PRODUCT_NAME");
```

Also, if your database has more fields or tables then you are mapping, it can give you many  errors. To resolve them, you need to set `use_proxy_validator` to `false` in your configuration.

**EDIT:**
NHibernate requires an Id column to work properly. I don't even know that if it does work without actually having a column declared as an Id column. Even if you declare `Ptoduct` as an Id column, you will not be able to properly query the database as querying for any of all objects with the same `Ptoduct` will return the topmost object.

Comment: Hi Yogesh, i have mapped Id to product because table don't contain an id column (i.e. identity column or may say auto increment column) and as per my knowledge fluent is making the this for (id Column in my object) on the flow at runtime by providing primary key column.. am i correct..??? thankx